# Кнопка и соседний div одной высоты в одном контейнере

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать кнопку одной высоты с рядом стоящим `div` (высота динамичная), не прибегая к табличному стилю, учитывая, что `div` и кнопка находятся в разных директивах, но в одном контейнере?

При использовании `height: 100%` в обоих элементах эффект такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сниппет с примером кода (не запускаемый)

```css
.main-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-navbar {
  flex: 0 1 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-main-content {
  flex: 2 0 0;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
/*legacy code, т.е. то, что мне надо сейчас переделать, чтобы работало с flex*/

.hideable-left-bar {
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 133, 196);
  width: 24em !important;
  min-height: 28.5em;
  background: rgba(0, 138, 255, 0.08);
  margin-left: 1em !important;
  margin-top: 1em;
  height: 100%;
}
.hideable-leftbar-button {
  border-top-right-radius: 5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5em;
  align-self: stretch;
  height: inherit;
  width: 2em;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 133, 196);
  border-left: none !important;
  padding-top: 2em;
  background: rgba(0, 138, 255, 0.08);
}
.my-button {
  absolute;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-flex-container">
  <div class="flex-navbar">
    <my-hideable-bar>
      @*составляющие дерективы*@
      <container class="hideable-left-bar">
        @*transclude starts*@
        <div>
          <my-directive-with-content>--- меню ---</my-directive-with-content>
        </div>
        @*end of transclude*@
        <span class="hideable-leftbar-button">
          <button class="my-button">Та самая кнопка</button>
        </span>
      </container>
    </my-hideable-bar>
    <div class="flex-main-content">
      ---основной контент---
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если у вас кнопка указана как `button`, то присвойте ей ещё стиль: `display: inline-block;` Если не поможет, то покажу пример с flexbox

Comment: Кнопка button, да. Я пробовала с inline-block, тоже не помогло к сожалению. Постараюсь скоро пример сделать, там заковыристо, надо подумать, как его в простой перевести.

Comment: Короче говоря, у вас button и div в одном блоке, у обоих стоит height: 100%, но они не на всю высоту?

Comment: там сложнее: две директивы в одном блоке. кнопка во втором (кнопка убирает первый блок). Сам блок еще в общем контейнере, который flexbox. Т.е. этот блок один из элементов flexbox'a. И при 100% высоте кнопка растягивается до высоты основного контента, не смотря на то, что родной блок заканчивается с div'ом  (простите, что хреново объясняю, я пока еще ужасно разбираюсь в css). Наверное, стоит расписать структуру всё-таки.

Comment: Вставьте сюда вашу директиву и стили которые к ней относятся. Начиная с контейнера flexbox

Comment: Час от часу не легче

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось добиться нужного эффекта с flexbox, добавив еще один внешний div:

```
.flex-hideable-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;      
}

.hideable-left-bar {
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 133, 196);
  width: 24em !important;
  min-height: 28.5em;
  background: rgba(0, 138, 255, 0.08);
  margin-left: 1em !important;
  margin-top: 1em;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.hideable-leftbar-button {
    border-top-right-radius: 5em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5em;
    align-self:stretch;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 28.5em;
    width: 2em;     
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(70, 133, 196);
    border-left: none !important;
    padding-top: 2em;
    background:rgba(0, 138, 255, 0.08);
    flex: 0 1 0;
}
.my-button {  
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

С радостью рассмотрю советы по улучшению данного варианта!

Comment: В принципе я так и предполагал. По вашему коду не очень видно проблему явную)

Comment: В этом проекте всегда сложно увидеть явную проблему)) очень много всего там понамешано.

Comment: Вам нужно было разместить пример, которые повторял бы вашу проблему и выглядел бы просто

Comment: Вы правы. Надо учиться писать работающие упрощенные прмеры. Я только в рядах начинающих и переписать что-то имеющиеся без шаблонов пока сложно - либо с нуля, либо с трудом)

Comment: А чего вы вообще хотите добиться? Это общая кнопка какая-то? Зачем вам полная высота?

Comment: Кнопка сворачивает/разворачивает навбар, при свернутом состоянии она меньше, в развернутом по размеру навбара.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай общий div для них и задай тогда обеим высоту в 100%

Comment: не помогает. Добавлю скриншот для наглядности.